# How do I join these two DataFrames on shared values in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following (`df1`)-

```
   read_year  read_month      load  trading_block
0       2017           3  0.019582              0
1       2017           3  0.019460              0
2       2017           3  0.018888              0
3       2017           3  0.018940              0
4       2017           3  0.019114              0
```

And another like the following (`df2`)-

```
   read_year  read_month      lmp  trading_block
0       2009           1  37.5694              0
1       2009           1  34.5777              0
2       2009           1  33.7039              0
3       2009           1  33.1503              0
4       2009           1  33.8935              0
```

What I want is for `df2` to merge/join/concat (whichever one works) on only the years that match- `read_year`.

The expected output should look like the following-

```
   read_year  read_month      load  trading_block       lmp
0       2017           3  0.019582              0   32.1201
1       2017           3  0.019460              0   12.1230
2       2017           3  0.018888              0   40.2941
3       2017           3  0.018940              0   20.3918
4       2017           3  0.019114              0   50.9371
```

How do I go about doing this easily?

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on='read_year')`

Comment: I added expected output. @Wen I tried that and it adds suffixes with more columns as well as causes the `load` values to repeat...

Comment: How did those inputs produce that output?  Three are no matching years.

Comment: oh the dataframe was actually like 800,000 rows long so I just did `df.head()` to show a portion of the data just to get my point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but need helper columns for count duplicates by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), also specify columns by subset:

```
#changed years for match data
print (df2)
   read_year  read_month      lmp  trading_block
0       2009           1  37.5694              0
1       2009           1  34.5777              0
2       2017           1  33.7039              0
3       2017           1  33.1503              0
4       2017           1  33.8935              0

df1['g'] = df1.groupby('read_year').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('read_year').cumcount()

#need columns for join in subset + columns for add - here lmp column
df = df1.merge(df2[['read_year','g','lmp']],on=['read_year', 'g']).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
   read_year  read_month      load  trading_block      lmp
0       2017           3  0.019582              0  33.7039
1       2017           3  0.019460              0  33.1503
2       2017           3  0.018888              0  33.8935
```

Comment: It seems to have worked but I'm still getting suffixed columns- `df.columns` - `Index([u'read_year', u'read_month_x', u'load', u'trading_block_x',
       u'read_month_y', u'lmp', u'trading_block_y'],
      dtype='object')`